# How to get the radius of Bohr from the uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, estimation, orbitals

I would like to know how to get the following result:
\begin{eqnarray}
a_0=\frac{4\pi\varepsilon_0 \hbar^2}{\mu e^2}
\end{eqnarray}
from the beginning of the uncertainty of heisenberg. If possible, I would like as much detail as possible on the assumed basic hypotheses.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206382/the-size-of-an-atom-using-uncertainty-principle).

Answer (score -2):

That result does not really come from the uncertainty principle. It comes from quantization of angular momentum, as a postulate.

Consider the two body problem between a proton of mass $M$ and electron of mass $m$. They have charges $\pm e$, respectively. The relative position vector, from the proton to the electron, then follows the differential equation

$$\mu\frac{d^2\mathbf r}{dt}=-\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{r^2}\hat r$$

Which for a circular orbit of radius $R$ has the condition

$$\mu\frac{v^2}{R}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{R^2}$$

But we can write this in terms of the center of mass angular momentum:

$$L=m\frac{M}{m+M}Rv_e+M\frac{m}{M+m}Rv_p$$

Where 
$$v_e=\frac{M}{m+M}v$$
$$v_p=\frac{m}{m+M}v$$

Are the center of mass velocities. As such

$$L=\frac{mMRv}{m+M}=\mu Rv$$

$$v=\frac{L}{\mu R}$$

Substituting this into the circular orbit condition we get

$$\frac{L^2}{\mu R^3}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{R^2}$$

$$R=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0L^2}{\mu e^2}$$

If we then *postulate* that CM angular momentum is quantized as $L=n\hbar$ for integer $n$, we get

$$R_n=n^2\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{\mu e^2}=n^2a_0$$

Where

$$a_0=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{\mu e^2}$$

Is (the Bohr radius) defined as the smallest nonzero orbital radius possible.

**HOWEVER**, if we insist on using the uncertainty principle, we can get an *estimate* of the smallest orbital radius. When we squeeze uncetainty to a minimum, we should get something of order

$$\Delta x\Delta p \sim h$$

The position shold vary between the orbit extremes, giving us something of order

$$\Delta x\sim R$$

For the momentum, it should vary between the extremes of momentum and therefore

$$\Delta p\sim \mu v$$

This then gives us

$$\mu vR\sim h$$

Which you can see is pretty much the same as quantizing angular momentum and choosing small $n$. This gives us an estimate of the smallest possible radius as

$$a_0\sim \frac{4\pi\epsilon_0h^2}{\mu e^2}$$

Which is only off by a factor of $(h/\hbar)^2=(2\pi)^2\approx40$ which isn't that bad.

Comment: Or you could start with the correct version, $\Delta x\Delta p \sim \hbar$, and get it right in one go.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the notion of the right form of the uncertainty principle goes quite deep. It is, however, well agreed that we should use $h$ when using characteristic dimensions (as I did) and $\hbar$ when using true uncertainties.

Comment: For reference, there is this really nice paper on olympiad quantum mechanics [here](https://www.ioc.ee/~kalda/ipho/quant_ENG.pdf)